# How to enable discover role when joining a channel from a peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I am having following error when trying to execute a transaction using the Discovery service from Fabric Java SDK

```
org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ServiceDiscoveryException: The channel is not configured with any peers with the 'discover' role
```

I joined the channel using peer shell command, not the Fabric Java SDK. How can I configure that discover role in the channel once it is already joined?

Thanks

Comment: You can check the following link for more details with another approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709303/the-channel-is-not-configured-with-any-peers-with-the-discover-role?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the exact missing part of code. Hope it helps someone with a similar issue. It was just a matter of adding the required peerRoles as @david_k comments:

I had:

```
channel.addPeer(peer);
```

and replacing it with this fixed the issue:

```
channel.addPeer(peer, createPeerOptions().setPeerRoles(EnumSet.of(PeerRole.SERVICE_DISCOVERY, PeerRole.LEDGER_QUERY, PeerRole.EVENT_SOURCE, PeerRole.CHAINCODE_QUERY)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of the `discover` role is a Fabric Java SDK concept. When you create your channel definition using the SDK and add a peer to it you would need to define that peer as having the discover role.

This is all handled for you if you use the fabric-gateway-java SDK package rather than the fabric-sdk-java package. The fabric-gateway-java package provides an easier entry into writing fabric client apps in java although not as powerful as using fabric-sdk-java.

Comment: OK, but is there a way to, once I create the channel using peer shell command, enable that "discover" role using fabric-sdk-java? How? (At the stage of the project we can't easily move to fabric-gateway-java now)

Comment: It's all down to how you create your peer object your code, you need to define that peer object and give it the discover role. This discover role is purely a java-sdk concept. Nothing to do with the peer server. You can make discovery calls to any peer. It's just that the java-sdk expects to know which peers you want to invoke discovery to.